# QueryDSL filter all elements in collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@ApiModelProperty("contains ignore case")
private String name;
@ApiModelProperty("equals")
private String department;
@ApiModelProperty("in equals")
private List<String> position;
@ApiModelProperty("greater or equals")
private Integer salaryFrom;
@ApiModelProperty("lower or equals")
private Integer salaryTo;
@ApiModelProperty("contains ignore case")
private String email;
@ApiModelProperty("at least one with priority higher")
private Integer oneHigher;
@ApiModelProperty("all priorities higher")
private Integer allHigher;

BooleanBuilder conditions = new BooleanBuilder();
ofNullable(salaryFrom).map(employee.salary::goe).ifPresent(conditions::and);
ofNullable(salaryTo).map(employee.salary::loe).ifPresent(conditions::and);
ofNullable(email).map(employee.email::containsIgnoreCase).ifPresent(conditions::and);
ofNullable(oneHigher).map(employee.tasks.any().priority::goe).ifPresent(conditions::and);                              
return conditions;
```

I have Employee entity that has set of `Task`, and I want to be able to query only for employees that have all tasks greater than certain priority, I was able to do that but when at least one task has priority greater than some value using any(), but I don't see a way to do that for all tasks because I don't see any way to iterate through tasks in `employee.tasks`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to model this with QueryDSL, but usually in HQL this can be modeled by using an exists subquery i.e. something like this:

```sql
from Employee e
where not exists (
  select 1
  from e.tasks t
  where t.priority < :priority
)
```

another way to formulate this is through using quantifiers

```sql
from Employee e
where :priority > all (
  select t.priority
  from e.tasks t
)
```